# SQL Queries/Subqueries

Tags: sql

I was wondering if someone could help me with this query? I am very stuck on this one:

"Show the sum of HoursWorked for each Type of OWNER but exclude services of employees who have ExperienceLevel of Junior and exclude any Type with less than three members."

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER
(
OwnerID     Int             NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)     PRIMARY KEY,
OwnerName   Char(30)        NOT NULL,
OwnerEmail  VarChar(100)    NULL,
OwnerType   Char(15)        NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE PROPERTY
(
PropertyID      Int         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)      PRIMARY KEY,
PropertyName    Char(30)    NOT NULL,   
Street          Char(20)    NOT NULL,
City            Char(25)    NOT NULL,
State           Char(10)    NOT NULL,   
Zip             Char(5)     NOT NULL,
OwnerID         Int         NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT  PROP_OWN_FK FOREIGN KEY(OwnerID)
            REFERENCES OWNER(OwnerID),
);

CREATE TABLE GG_EMPLOYEE
(
EmployeeID      Int         NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)      PRIMARY KEY,
LastName        Char(35)    NOT NULL,
FirstName       Char(35)    NOT NULL,
CellPhone       Char(20)    NOT NULL,
ExperienceLevel Char(25)    NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE SERVICE 
(
PropertyID      Int         NOT NULL,
EmployeeID      Int         NOT NULL,
ServiceDate     Char(15)    NOT NULL,
HoursWorked     Char(5)     NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT  SERVICE_PK  PRIMARY KEY(PropertyID, EmployeeID, ServiceDate),
CONSTRAINT  SER_PRO_FK FOREIGN KEY(PropertyID)
            REFERENCES PROPERTY(PropertyID),                        
CONSTRAINT  SER_GG_EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID)
            REFERENCES GG_EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID),
);
```

Comment: yes i did, they might not be exactly right, but that shouldn't matter with the subqueries, right?

Comment: Can you share output with some data?

Comment: What's a member? Is that supposed to be exclude any owner type with less than 3 owners?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you most definitely do **not** want to use the `char` data type. Use `varchar` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.OwnerType, SUM(Cast(HoursWorked as INT)) Sum_HrsWorked
FROM SERVICE s 
INNER JOIN GG_EMPLOYEE e
ON s.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN PROPERTY p
ON s.PropertyId = p.PropertyId
INNER JOIN OWNER o
ON o.OwnerID = p.OwnerID
WHERE e.ExperienceLevel <> 'JUNIOR'
Group By o.OwnerType
HAVING COUNT(OwnerType) > 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Tbl1.OwnerName,Sum(TBl2.TTLHoursWorked) as TTLHoursWorked
From
(
    Select TBl1.OwnerID,Tbl1.OwnerName,Tbl2.PropertyID,Tbl2.PropertyName
    From Owner Tbl1
    Inner Join
    PROPERTY Tbl2
    On Tbl1.OwnerID=Tbl2.OwnerID
)Tbl1
Inner Join
(
    Select Tbl2.PropertyID,Cast(HoursWorked as numeric(5,4)) as TTLHoursWorked
    From (Select * From GG_EMPLOYEE Where ExperienceLevel in(Select ExperienceLevel   
                                                            From GG_EMPLOYEE
                                                            Where ExperienceLevel<>'Junior' 
                                                            Group by ExperienceLevel Having Count(*)>3))as Tbl1 
    Inner Join SERVICE as Tbl2
    On  Tbl1.EmployeeID=Tbl2.EmployeeID
)Tbl2
On Tbl1.PropertyID=Tbl2.PropertyID
Group by Tbl1.OwnerName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.OwnerType, SUM(CAST(s.HoursWorked as INT))
FROM
     owner o
     INNER JOIN property p 
     On o.ownerid = p.ownerid
     INNER JOIN service s
      ON p.propertyid = s.propertyid
     INNER JOIN GG_employee e
     On s.employeeid = e.employeeid
     And e.experiencelevel <> 'junior'
GROUP BY
   O.ownertype
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.ownerid) >= 3
```

Please forgive typos and capitalization as I'm on my phone.